# Change the highlight color of text pasted into terminal

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, 21.04, colors

In the recent version of gnome terminal, when text is pasted into the terminal, it is initially highlighted in white.

[image]

I would like to change this *paste-highlight* color to something else  (preferably light gray).

How can I achieve this?

I assume this can be configured in `~/.bashrc`, but I may be wrong.

(Please note, I am not talking about the terminal highlight color that can be set in gnome terminal's preferences).

Comment: I assume it may rather be a setting in the gnome-terminal application.

Comment: See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash/+bug/1926256 .

Comment: @N0rbert, thanks for linking to the bug report; I am already subscribed to it. Based on Egmont Koblinger's comment in the bug report, the highlighting of pasted text is a feature of bash 5.1. My question is, can we make the highlighting *color* something different? Because this highlighting is controlled by bash, I thought there might be something we can add to `~/.bashrc` to change the color (not disable or remove the highlighting "feature").

Comment: Bash 5.2 allows you to customize the pasted text's colors. See the latest comments behind the aforementioned link.